# Add write permissions for chroot user on centOS 6

Tags: permissions, chroot

I've a jailed user "ftest" (in /home/ftest) but he can't create files or folders within the jail.

User was added by:

```
useradd -g nginx -G sftpjail -s /bin/false
```

Permissions and owners are:

```
755 root:sftpjail /home/ftest
755 ftest:nginx /home/ftest/test1
755 ftest:sftpjail /home/ftest/test2
777 ftest:nginx /home/ftest/test3
```

The chroot sftp login is working just fine, but unfortunately it's not possible to write to any of the testX folders.

Comment: afaik jail exists only on FreeBSD. Are you talking about chroot or jail?

Comment: You are right, sorry! chroot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the ftest user doesn't have write permissions on his home directory.

/home/ftest is owned by root user and sftpjail group. ftest is indeed a member of sftpjail, but the 755 permission means the group can only read, not write from there.

You have 2 options here, either change the ownership to ftest:sftpjail, and keep the permissions 755, or keep theownership as is, but change permissions to 775.

I believe creating files inside the test folders is working fine though, right?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option. I tried both but the chroot only works with root:root and 755

Comment: what do you mean by "only works with.."? is there some error? can you elaborate?

Comment: If the rights of the home directory are wrong I can't login via sftp. I always get asked for a password which is not set for ftest user which has an rsa-key set.

Comment: but that relates to the permissions of .ssh/authorized_keys only, no?

Comment: No, the log says: "bad ownership or modes for chroot directory"